# What is behavior: url(); property in css?

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I was surfing and saw this css property which I have never seen or used before. I think it is related to Internet Explorer, and the structure is something like this:

```
#element{
  behavior: url(something.htc);
}
```

What does the `behavior` property do? How would I use this property?

I did find this [w3 Documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/WD-becss-19990804#behavior), but it's not particularly clear what it does.

[image]

Comment: it's used to attach code to a dom element. major usage I've seen around was to attach filters to .png images to allow transparency on older versions of IE.

Comment: Don't use this, or worry about it. It's a mere footnote in the history of the web.

Comment: The W3C document quoted is an outdated draft, from 1999; there is a newer draft, from 2007, which does not describe this property.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

### It is Microsoft Extensions to CSS

> .htc files are commonly used in .css files using an IE specific property called behavior, using this along with the .htc file allows the browser to run JavaScript code which is whats contained within the file.

### what it does?

Sets or retrieves the location of the [Dynamic HTML (DHTML) behaviorDHTML Behaviors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ie/ms531079(v=vs.85).aspx).

### .htc Extention

The script resides in an HTC (HTML Component) file. HTC files have the extension .htc, and are HTML files that contain a script plus a set of HTC-specific elements that define the components.

### [- History of behavior](http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/css/properties/dynamic/behavior.htm)

---

### Syntax

behavior: url(sLocation) | url(#objID) | url(#default#behaviorName)

### Property values

**url(sLocation)**

- Script implementation of a DHTML behavior, where sLocation is an absolute or relative URL.

**url(#objID)**

- Binary implementation of a DHTML behavior, where objID is the ID attribute specified in an object tag.

**url(#default#behaviorName)**

- The application's  default behavior, identified by its behaviorName.

---

### Useful Links

- [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ie/ms530723(v=vs.85).aspx)
- [Site Point](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/behavior)
- [CSS3.COM](http://www.css3.com/css-behavior/)
- [Dottoro](http://help.dottoro.com/lcocnjbn.php)
- [CSS Standards Support](http://htmlcss.wikia.com/wiki/-ms-behavior)
- [htmlcss.wikia.com](http://htmlcss.wikia.com/wiki/-ms-behavior)

### [Microsoft says it is no longer supported in IE 10!](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh801216%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: You ask a question and answer on your own. Why ask them in the first place?

Comment: Asked then googled it found someinformation! here in stackoverflow we can answer our own questions, So answeres http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: Ok that, alright. Now accept the answer after 48 hrs.

Answer (score 4):

It lets you use CSS to attach a script to a specific element in order to implement DHTML (Dynamic HTML) components.

Internet Explorer versions 5 and later support the behavior property.
Internet Explorer 8 supports Vendor specific format of **-ms-behavior**

For more info. refer this [link](https://htmlcss.fandom.com/wiki/-ms-behavior).

Comment: Support was dropped in IE 10 (except when it is set to emulate older versions).